# jQuery appendTo() html of div to another div - TypeError: text.appendTo is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

I have a notes in div, and after click on note I nned to take note `html` and `appendTo` as last child of another div

```
$('.note-single').click(function(){
    var text = $('div', $(this)).html();
    text.appendTo( $('.note-editable.panel-body')[0] );
});
```

This returns me an error: Uncaught TypeError: text.append is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The `html()` method returns a string which does not have an `appendTo()` method - hence the error. To fix it, you could use the `append()` method of a jQuery object, like this:

```
$('.note-single').click(function(){
    var html = $('div', $(this)).html();
    $('.note-editable.panel-body:first').append(html);
});
```

Alternatively, you could clone the element directly instead of building a new set of elements from a HTML string:

```
$('.note-single').click(function(){
    $('div', $(this)).clone().appendTo('.note-editable.panel-body:first');
});
```

Note that I used the `:first` selector here as I presumed that your usage of `[0]` on the selector was to get the first element in the matched set, and not that you specifically wanted to return the underlying DOMElement.